# SSIS - How to dynamically pick a csv file from a folder based on timestamp in the file name

Tags: sql, ssis, file-transfer

I have a requirement to move a csv file from a source folder into target folder. Below is the naming format of the file to picked and moved.

*Report_File_CSV_MMDDYYY.csv*

I have to pick the file which starts with "Report_File_CSV_" and MMDDYYY is the dynamic part. There can multiple files for different dates, I have to pick up the file based on the latest date. Also, there will be other Excel files which I have to ignore and pick the mentioned file.

If the solution is out somewhere already, any pointers will be highly appreciated.

I just started working with SSIS packages from couple of weeks. I have 6 months experience working with SQL Server.

Thanks in advance and cheers.

Comment: Which language or tool are you comfortable using ?

Comment: Just read the files then sort them and work out which has the higher YYY, then of those which has the highest MM, then DD, eg: `Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderBase + "\files", "*.csv")
 System.Array.Sort(Of String)(Files)`

Comment: @AnkurBajaj - SSIS previously only supported VB.Net, does it now support other languages?

Comment: I can manage to to write basic .net @AnkurBajaj

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question using C# utilizing LINQ.

```
string file = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\path").GetFiles()
                   .Where(e => e.Extension.EndsWith("csv"))
                   .Where(s => s.Name.StartsWith("Report_File_CSV_"))
                   .OrderByDescending(d => 
                          d.Name.Substring(d.Name.Length - 3,3) + //YYY part
                          d.Name.Substring(d.Name.Length - 7,4) //MMDD part
                                      )
                   .Select(f => f.FullName)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

The other answer: [SSIS - Loop through text files sorted in creation order and process each record on each file as an update or an insert into a SQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685072/ssis-loop-through-text-files-sorted-in-creation-order-and-process-each-record/68717861#68717861)

Is sorted by file create date which might also work for you.